# Shorter way for writing expression

Tags: functions, integers

I'm writing the following expression in a long expression

$$
\left( 1+(-1)^m+(-1)^n+(-1)^{m+n}\right),
$$
for integer $m,\ n$. This equals $4$ if both $m$ and $n$ are even, and equals $0$ otherwise. I am writing this in a long expression, which makes that this awkward term breaks the line, while if I could make it a bit shorter, it would fit. Is there a way I'm overseeing, to write this expressin shorter?

I've thought of writing it as $F(m,n)$, where

$$
F(m,n)=\begin{cases}
4 \text{ if }m ,\  n\text{ even}\\
0 \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
But I would like to avoid having to introduce a new function in an expression which is already long and difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not $(1+(-1)^m)(1+(-1)^n)$? Or since we're limited to integers, $(-1)^m=\cos\pi m\implies 1+(-1)^m=2\cos^2\frac{\pi m}{2}$, so you could use $4\cos^2\frac{\pi m}{2}\cos^2\frac{\pi n}{2}$. Finally, with [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) you could write $4[2|m][2|n]$, $4[2|m\land 2|n]$ or $4\left[2|\left(m,\,n\right)\right]$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately this does not help me much. For the first  two suggestions, this is inline actually a bit longer, making it less desirable. The last is very short and nice, but is also uncommon notation in my field, making me have to explain this notation as well, which I also would like to avoid.

Comment: @User123456789 How is $4\cos^2\frac{\pi m}{2}\cos^2\frac{\pi n}{2}$ longer than $1+(-1)^m+(-1)^n+(-1)^{m+n}$? Longer to type, yes, but it's shorter in print.

Comment: I've tried and it is indeed a bit shorter, I misaligned something making it look longer at first. In fact it is just short enough to let the expression fit the line. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be $$2-2(-1)^{(m-1)(n-1)}$$

Comment: I can see this is the same formula by comparison, but in case you derived it from the first one, can you give me an idea of how you did it?

Comment: I derived it from scratch.  I knew you wanted to distinguish $m,n$ even from the other $3$ possibilities ($m$ even, $n$ odd; $m$ odd, $n$ even; and $m,n$ odd).  The sum of $n$ and $m$ distinguishes two cases from the other two; the product distinguishes one case (odd$\times$odd) from the other three.  So I took the product of $n-1$ and $m-1$ to distinguish the even/even case from the others and adjusted the coefficients to get the result you wanted.  How does it compare with the other suggestions for shortness?

Comment: In my opinion is the shortest but I think also an expression is the simplest when given by its factors so I like $(1+(-1)^m)(1+(-1)^n)$ too, at the end I suppose it depends what OP had in mind for shortness